# How to find the views of a particular schema that have nullable columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a huge database in which there are nearly 200 views of a particular schema. I need to find all the views has the nullable columns and also the column names that can be nullable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the catalog views to find the information you need. Example below:

```
select  schema_name(V.schema_id) as schemaname, 
        object_name(V.object_id) as viewname, 
        C.name as columnname 
from sys.columns C
join sys.views V
on C.object_id = V.object_id
where is_nullable = 1 and is_ms_shipped = 0
order by schemaname, viewname, columnname;
```

Comment: That is pretty much exactly my answer, too.